# How to configure html for selectfield(wtforms) flask?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Good evening to everyone who reads this post.
I want to add a select box to my web site in flask, but i can not understand how to set up html for that
I look forward to see any comments and suggestions :)

My python code:

```
class selectmenu(Form):
    month = SelectField('Choose month',choices=[('dec', 'dec'), ('yan', 'yan'), ('feb', 'febt')])

@app.route('/searchemp/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def searchemp():
    form = selectmenu(request.form)
    m = form.month.data
```

HTML:

```html
<form action="" class="form-signin" method="post">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">title</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       placeholder= "username" name="username" value="{{request.form.username}}" required autofocus>
                                <!--
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                               placeholder= "month" name="month" value="{{request.form.month}}">
                                -->
                                                         <select name="month">
                                                         <option value="{{request.form.month}}">dec</option>
                                                         <option value="{{request.form.month}}">yanuary</option>
                                                         <option value="{{request.form.month}}">feb</option>
                                                         <option value="{{request.form.month}}">mar</option>
                                                       </select>
 
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
                    <br>
                    <p align="center">{{error}} </p>
                </form>
```

Comment: Missing `<form` in first line.

Comment: i've edited the question. Could you give any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 template engine will render selectfield with choices, you dont have to create a html select field, jinja2 already does. And if you need to check form submission use `validate_on_submit()` or `request.method == 'POST'`:

```
class SelectMenu(Form):
    month = SelectField('Select Month', choices=[(1, 'January'), (2,'February')])

@app.route('/searchemp/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def searchemp():
    form = SelectMenu(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # get posted data
        m = form.month.data
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

# index.html
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{form.month.label}}{{form.month}}
</form>
```